# XML Schema reading/editing in vim?

Tags: xml, vim, schema, xsd

As XML Schemas can be tedious to read (yes, just want to read through the schema) in their normal form, I'm wondering if anyone knows of an existing plugin for vim which will display the schema in tree form, as several XML editors do? Selection of a node in this tree to navigate to the relevant section of the schema would be a good plus, but not absolutely necessary.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize that you're looking for something different, but check out `xml.vim`. From the information available on the [vimscripts website](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1397), it says it's capable of:

> - closing tags while you type
> - optional adding attributes
> - % matches end or begin tag
> - folding tags, comments and Cdata
> - adding start tag, end tags
> - adding tags around a visual block or a tag,
> - joining 2 adjacent same tags
> - deletings tag or tag sections
> - changing a tag

After you having it installed (by placing it in `.vim/ftplugin`, type `:help xml-plugin` for more information. You might be able to add a `autocmd` and fold all tags on buffer entry. That way you can traverse the xml file just as you would with a normal xml editor.

Comment: I am indeed familiar with this. I like your folding idea. I was looking for something similar to NERDtree, but with the XML elements in a file instead of files and folders.

Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if anything like that exists, unfortunately. You could always write one, though! =)

Comment: for those who didn't know : put `filetype plugin on` in your ~/.vimrc to make vi automatically load xml.vim when you load an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [xmledit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301) and  [XML folding](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1438) can improve your experience.